# Track changes VBA code-How to rewrite this code?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop, excel-formula

**Question:** My question is how can i expand my ranges to applied the below ranges. If i apply all the ranges the code will become too long. I am looking for a more efficient way of writing it.

I am trying to apply a macro to my project which tracks changes once  the cell ranges below are changed and file is saved( both conditions to be met).  I am trying to make the code more dynamic and efficient(shorter).

**My Ranges:**
Sheet3.Range D ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)

Sheet3.Range E ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)

I have a worksheet called Dates, where the track changes are recorded.  With three columns:

username (Environ("Username")) column A , Date in column B and Time in column C.

**Problem 2**
When the cells in sheet3 are later updated. I need the information in sheet(“Dates”) updated with a new additional line ,but if this new date occurs in the same week as the dates already there, it should update that row. So I am trying to avoid dates in the same week being saved. The objective is to record when the tasks were last done for each week

```
'set as public variables to remain saved while workbook is open
Public val1, val2, val3, val4, Val5

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'set the variables when the workbook is opened
Call SetValues
End Sub

Private Sub SetValues()
'save the values to be checked later
val1 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D20").Value
val2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D24").Value
val3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D25").Value
val4 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D27").Value
Val5 = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D28").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDates As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Long, updateRow As Long, x As Long
Dim checkDate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set wsDates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dates")

'if the values have been changed
If _
val1 <> ws.Range("D20").Value Or _
val2 <> ws.Range("D24").Value Or _
val3 <> ws.Range("D25").Value Or _
val4 <> ws.Range("D27").Value Or _
Val5 <> ws.Range("D28").Value Then

    'reset the values to avoid multiple updates
    Call SetValues

    'set the range of values to check
    endRow = wsDates.Cells(wsDates.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'check to see if an entry was found the same week
    For x = 1 To endRow
        checkDate = wsDates.Cells(x, 2).Value
        If checkDate >= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1) And checkDate <= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1 + 7) Then
            updateRow = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    'if an entry the same week wasn't found, set update row to new row
    If updateRow = 0 Then updateRow = endRow + 1

    'update or add information
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 1).Formula = Application.UserName
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 2).Formula = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 3).Formula = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @YowE3K please see code is question thanks

Comment: Do the users ever reset their computer's system date so that the current date might be earlier than the last time that the spreadsheet was saved?  If not, the only date you ever need to look at in the "Dates" sheet is the one in `endRow` - anything else must be in a week earlier than the current week.

Comment: @YowE3K users do not reset their computer's system date.

Comment: In that case, your `For x = 1 To endRow` may as well just be `For x = endRow To endRow` (or just `x = endRow` and then get rid of the `Next`).  What actual problem are you having with your code?  It isn't very clear from the question whether you are just looking for improvement to working code (in which case it should **possibly** be posted on Code Review, but definitely not on Stack Overflow) or whether it is doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @YowE3K My question is how can i expand my ranges to applied the above ranges. If i apply all the ranges the code will become too long. I am looking for a more efficient way of writing it.

Comment: This almost certainly shouldn't be asked here then, but until someone closes it and says to put it on Code Review, I'll keep asking questions.  Do you care whether a log entry is created if, for instance, cell D21 is changed?  (If not, you could just load D20:E65 in an array and do everything in a loop.  If you don't want a change to D21 logged, it gets complicated.)

Comment: @YowE3K yes i do not want D21 changes to be logged. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153515/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would structure the code for this task.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        'set the variables when the workbook is opened
        GetValues True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
        ' 02 Sep 2017

        If HasChanges Then
            WriteLog
            'reset the values to avoid multiple updates
            GetValues True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function HasChanges() As Boolean
       ' 02 Sep 2017

        Dim Prev As Variant, Curr As Variant
        Dim R As Long, C As Long
        Dim i As Long

        Prev = GetValues
        Curr = CheckRange.Value
        For i = LBound(Prev) To UBound(Prev)
            For C = LBound(Prev, 2) To UBound(Prev, 2)
                If Curr(i, C) <> Prev(i, C) Then
                    R = i + AllRows(0) - LBound(Prev)
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(R, AllRows, 0)) Then
                        HasChanges = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
            Next C
        Next i
    End Function

    Private Sub WriteLog()
        ' 02 Sep 2017

        Dim WsDates As Worksheet
        Dim checkDate
        Dim endRow As Long, updateRow As Long
        Dim R As Long

        With WsDates
            endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            'check to see if an entry was found the same week
            For R = 1 To endRow
                checkDate = .Cells(R, 2).Value
                If (checkDate >= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1)) And _
                   (checkDate <= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1 + 7)) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next R

            'if an entry the same week wasn't found, set update row to new row
            updateRow = R

            'update or add information
            With .Rows(updateRow)
                .Cells(1).Formula = Application.UserName
                .Cells(2).Formula = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                .Cells(3).Formula = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")
            End With
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Function GetValues(Optional ByVal ResetValues As Boolean) As Variant
        ' 02 Sep 2017

        ' if called without parameters, this function returns the value last set
        ' if called with ResetValues = True or if never called during current session
          ' it returns the current values

        Static Fun As Variant
        Dim Rng As Range

        If ResetValues Or (VarType(Fun) = 0) Then Fun = CheckRange.Value
        GetValues = Fun
    End Function

    Private Function AllRows() As Variant
        ' 02 Sep 2017

        AllRows = Array(20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, _
                        40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)
    End Function

    Private Function CheckRange() As Range
        ' 02 Sep 2017

        With Worksheets("Sheet3")
            Set CheckRange = .Range(.Cells(AllRows(0), "D"), _
                                    .Cells(AllRows(UBound(AllRows)), "E"))
        End With
    End Function
```

Comment: thanks for that. But im getting an error of "object variable or with block variable not set"  on   endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row